# Update Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data

How to update databes ?
I wrote it

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Product SET description = :description, inStock = :inStock, name = :name, price = :price WHERE id = :id")

void updateProduct(@Param("description") String description, @Param("inStock") int inStock, @Param("name") String name, @Param("price") int price, @Param("id") int id);
```

Athought, i think that it is bad.
This is good practice?
How to do better?
How to transfer full object to  Query?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create custom method, just use `save()` method of your repository, for example:

```
@Service
public class ProductService {

    @Autoware
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Transaction
    public void updatePrice(Product product, int price) { 
        product.setPrice(price);
        productRepository.save(product);
    }
}
```